# Evaluating $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> Compute:$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

I and my friend came across this product. Is the product till infinity equal to $1$?

If no, what is the answer?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks the result is $\approx 2.384231029031371724149899$.

Comment: Wasn't the problem something like this instead? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183416/compute-the-infinite-product-prod-limits-n-2-infty-left1-frac12n-2?rq=1 Because the answer should be none of the above.

Comment: Solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922298/closed-form-of-infinite-product-prod-limits-k-0-infty-left1-frac12?rq=1

Comment: WA says:
$\prod_{n=0}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}})=2$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is the product till infinity equal to $1$?

Certainly not! All the individual terms are greater than $1$. So if you multiply them together, you will always be increasing and cannot get back to $1$.

> If no, what is the answer?

The product in question is
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + x^n)
$$
where $x = \frac12$. This product equals
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty q(n) x^n
$$
where $q(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts (each part $\ge 1$), and also equals
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - x^{2n-1}} = \frac{\Phi(x^2)}{\Phi(x)}
$$
(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts)), where here $\Phi$ is [the Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), not to be confused with Euler's totient function.
So your product is equal to
$$
\boxed{\frac{\Phi(1/4)}{\Phi(1/2)} = 2.38423\ldots}.
$$
I don't expect this can be simplified.

Comment: Can you please see his updated question and try to answer the same way? I am quite interested.

Comment: @WinVineeth I assume you're referring to the different product that came up in the comments, which was the problem the OP got this from? That is $2$, and it is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922298/closed-form-of-infinite-product-prod-limits-k-0-infty-left1-frac12?rq=1).

Comment: Don't delete this answer. It's great and correctly answers the original question. If the OP wants to ask something different, they can simply open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

In the link you provided, the product seems to be $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right)$$

Note that $$(1-\frac{1}{2})\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}})=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n+1}}}=1$$
From the fact that $$(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^k}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k}})=1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k+1}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m 2^{mn}}=\exp\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m(2^m-1)} $$
where the last series is (rapidly) convergent by Leibniz' test. It follows that the original product is between $\exp\left(\frac{121}{140}\right)$ and $\exp\left(\frac{3779}{4340}\right)$. By truncating the shown series at $m=30$ we get
$$\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\approx 2.384231029.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to obtain the same answer of 6005. If we take the log of this product and the Taylor expansion of log we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k2^{mk}}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k\left(1-2^{k}\right)}=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k2^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)}
 $$ $$=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k4^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^{k}}\right)}+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k2^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)}
 $$ and since we have $$\log\left(\Phi\left(q\right)\right)=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{q^{n}}{k\left(1-q^{n}\right)}
 $$ where $\Phi\left(q\right)
 $ is the [Euler's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k2^{mk}}=\log\left(\frac{\Phi\left(1/4\right)}{\Phi\left(1/2\right)}\right).
 $$ As wrote by 6005, probably there is no simplification for this result. The result can be written also as a [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) $$\prod_{n\geq1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)=\left(-1;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer. There are already full answers posted.

I can prove that the sequence $x_n=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$ converges, is strictly increasing and less than $e$, so $\prod_{i=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)\le e$. Notice that $x_n>0$, $\forall n$, so $x_{n+1}=x_n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)>x_n$, $\forall n$. $$x_1=1.5\le x_n=e^{\ln\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)}=$$

$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)<\frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n\ge 1$, $n\in\mathbb Z$ is true. A more general inequality $e^x> x+1$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, $x\neq 0$ is also true.

$$=e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)}<e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}}<e^{\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}}=e$$

[WolframAlpha says that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(1%2B2%5E(-j)),+j%3D1+to+infinity) the infinite product is $\approx 2.384$.