# Find the value of the infinite product: $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{3^n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponentiation, cauchy-sequences, infinite-product

I am Anay, here is a problem I am stuck with:

$$x = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{3^n} \right )$$

The task is to find the value of $x$. (obviously, we aren't supposed to have infinite products or sums, etc. in the answer)

This is what I have done:

We define the sequence $a_{k}$ as,

$$a_{k} = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{k }\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{3^n} \right )$$

First, we put some bounds on $a_{k}$, as it is a increasing sequence, we already have the lower bound as $\frac{4}{3}$. Now to get the higher bound, we have the following inequality for all integers $x$ (easily proved through binomial expansion):

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} < e$$

So,

$$(1+x) < e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Using this inequality many times, we have, (using the formula for sum of a geometric progression)

$$a_{k} < e^2$$

Thus,

$$\frac{4}{3}\leq a_{k}< e^2$$

Then, to prove that this sequence is converging we show that it has the Cauchy Property. This can be done as follows:

First, we have,

$$a_{k} = a_{k-1} + \frac{a_{k-1}}{3^k}$$

So adding such equations for $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$ ..... $a_{k}$, we see that all terms cancel out and the following remains:

$$a_{k} = a_{1} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k-1}\frac{a_{i}}{3^{i+1}}$$

So, if $m < n$,

$$a_{n} - a_{m} = \sum\limits_{i=m}^{n-1} \frac{a_{i}}{3^{i+1}} < a_{n-1}\left(\frac{3^{n} - 3^{m}}{3^{m+n}\times2 }\right)$$

As $a_{k}$ is a increasing sequence, we have used $a_{n-1} > a_{n-2}>....>a_{m} $. And then we use the formula for sum of a geometric progression to get the result. Now we can see that when $m$ and $n$ are large enough, we can have the RHS arbitrarily small as $a_{n-1}$ has a upper bound ($e^2$), thus the sequence has the Cauchy property and it is converging.

After this I thought may be the sequence converges to the bound which I established ($e^2$), but it is not so as I checked it through a computer program, it approaches around $1.56$, which is far below $e^2$. So, after this I try many other methods to find where the sequence converges to but I found no luck. Also, I couldn't find any results on Google, so I have come to your help. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks the result is ≈1.564934018567011537938849106728835416569425919895035009496...

Comment: @SubratKumarJena Yeah, my computer program showed it accurately till 1.564934018567011. But how do we approach the problem 'mathematically', without taking help of computers? Also, is there anything special about the above number? How can we express it without listing all the decimals, like with some irrational constant or some surd or something?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol In summary: there are no simple closed form for this product in elementary functions. Try to approximate it instead.

Comment: $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{n}}\right)=\frac{\left(-1;\frac{1}{3}\right)_{\infty}}{2}$.

Comment: See the link:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924882/what-is-the-product-prod-n-1-infty-left1-frac12n-right

Comment: A good approximation is $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{3^n}\right) \approx e^{\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^k}}\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1+\frac{1}{3^n}\right)$$ for any integer $k$. The higher $k$ the better the approximation. For example for $k=4$ it gives $\frac{91840 \sqrt[162]{e}}{59049} \simeq 1.56495$ while the exact answer is $\simeq 1.56493$.

Comment: @Winther And how do we get to that approximation?

Comment: Use $\left(1+\frac{1}{3^n}\right) = e^{\log(1 + 1/3^n)} \approx e^{\frac{1}{3^n}}$ valid for large $n$ (since $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$) to get $\prod \left(1+\frac{1}{3^n}\right) \approx \prod e^{\frac{1}{3^n}} = e^{\sum \frac{1}{3^n}}$. I then choose to take the explicit product of the first $k$ terms and use the approximation on the rest.

Comment: @Winther, Okay, got it.

Comment: @Winther I will look into both Q-Pochhammer and Euler function and study it a bit, thanks. I don't think I understood all that right now.

Comment: @SubratKumarJena Thanks, I will study the sloution given to the other problem and look into Q-Pochhammer and the Euler function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^2}\right)=1+\frac13+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{3^3}$$

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^3}\right)=1+\frac13+\frac1{3^2}+\frac2{3^3}+\frac1{3^4}+\frac1{3^5}+\frac1{3^6}$$

I guess continuing this you can observe a pattern and it will leads to the solution.
Good luck

EDIT:
Above pattern shows us, the infinite summation can be written as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{q(n)}{3^n},$$ where $q$ is the [partition  function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) So there is no closed form involving elementary functions.

Comment: There is no simple pattern that allows a simple solution here. The solution can formally be written in terms of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function - these are non-elementary functions (defined as infinite products) and do not have a simple representation.

Comment: Yes. Just now I realize that the pattern involves the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) and it is non-elementary.

Comment: uh? I don't see how this pattern can help in a infinite sequence

Comment: We define Infinite products as the limit of a finite product. So there is a relationship between this pattern and your infinite product. :)