Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\prod_{x=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{2^x})$
Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\prod_{x=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{2^x})$
It can be proved that the limit exists because $\prod_{x=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{2^x}) < e^{\sum_{x=1}^n\ln(1+\frac{1}{2^x})} < e^{\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{1}{2^x}} < e$ and the product increase when n increase.
Python told me that the answer is approximately 2.38, but I wonder how to calculate the exact answer.
Or maybe no elementary expression?

Welcome to the site. I found this similar post using Approach zero search engine.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924882/evaluating-prod-n-1-infty-left1-frac12n-right?noredirect=1

Thanks a lot @user1380196. I didn't know that website before. It seems to be a hard problem. Thank you for the post link.

You're welcome. By the way I found the second link by searching $\prod_{x=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2^x})$ without "lim".
