Find $\lim u_n$ for $u_n = \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{4^k}\right).$

$u_n = \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{4^k}\right) = \left(1 + \frac{1}{4^1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{4^2}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{4^n}\right) \quad \forall n \geq 1.$
Show that $u_n$ converges and find the limit of convergence.

I was able to do the first part, but I struggled to find the limit. This is what I did.
We have $u_{n+1} - u_n = u_n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4^{n+1}}\right) - u_n = \dfrac{u_n}{4^{n+1}} > 0 \implies u_n$ is increasing.
On the other hand, $\ln{u_n} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4^k}\right)\leq \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{4^k}=\dfrac{1}{3}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4^n}\right)<\dfrac13\implies u_n$ is bounded above.
Therefore, $u_n$ converges by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.
I hope to receive some advice on how to tackle the limit. Thank you very much!

might able to do something by taking a natural log from both sides and fashion a Riemann sum approximation out of the sum.

That is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924903/42969 with $x=1/4$.

Probably too complex
Making the problem more general
$$u_n =\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+a^{-k}\right)\quad \implies \quad
\log(u_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log\Big(1+a^{-k}\Big)$$ Since we know that
$$\int \log\Big(1+a^{-k}\Big)\,dk=\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(-a^{-k}\right)}{\log (a)}$$ we can use the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation.
Taking the limit
$$\large\color{blue}{\log(u_\infty)=\frac{1}{2} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)
-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\log(a)}+
\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{P_n(a) }{ \alpha_n}A^{2n+1}}$$ where
$$\color{blue}{A=\frac{\log (a)}{a+1}}$$
The coefficients $\alpha_n$
$$\{12,720,30240,1209600\}$$ form sequence $A060055$ in $OEIS$.
Concerning the polynomials, they are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(a) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & a(a-1)  \\
 2 & a(a-1)  \left(a^2-10 a+1\right) \\
 3 & a(a-1)  \left(a^4-56 a^3+246 a^2-56 a+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Compared to the exact value (which we know formally), for $1 < a \leq 11$, the maximum absolute relative error is $0.00233$%.
For $a=4$, converted to decimals , the limit of the infinite summation is
$\color{red}{0.30447}21$ and the limit of the infinite product is $\color{red}{1.355909}05$.
For $a=2$ as in this post, the result would be $\color{red}{2.3842310}33$
